# How to change color of mat-chips within a mat-chip-list programmatically?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the mat-chips for filtering a table and everything seems to work just fine:

**home.html**

```
<mat-chip-list>
   <mat-chip (click)="onSectorChipSelect(sector)" [color]="chipColor(sector)" *ngFor="let sector of sectors" selected>{{sector}}</mat-chip>
   <mat-chip (click)="clearSectors()">
     Clear 
   </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

**home.ts** adding the sectors to a list called filteredSectors which holds all the selected sectors at a time.

```
onSectorChipSelect(sector: string) {
 if (this.filteredSectors.includes(sector)) {
  this.filteredSectors.splice(this.filteredSectors.indexOf(sector), 1);
 } else {
  this.filteredSectors.push(sector);
 }
}
```

**home.ts** this method colors the chip blue (primary) if selected, otherwise it stays white (basic).

```
chipColor(sector: string) {
  if (this.filteredSectors.includes(sector)) {
    return 'primary';
  }
  return 'basic';
}
```

the "problem" is that the method chipColor() is bound to the color attribute of the chip and therefore called several times when just scrolling or clicking around in the home component. My guess is that everytime the browser renders, the method is being called again? (i don't really know, maybe someone can explain?)

There are around 20 sectors so it's not really a performance issue I guess? It's just annoying to know and not a good practice I think. But how can I change that?

What I tried so far is setting the color of each chip to white (basic):

**home.html**

```
<mat-chip (click)="onSectorChipSelect(sector)" color="basic" *ngFor="let sector of sectors" selected>{{sector}}</mat-chip>
```

**home.ts**

```
  @ViewChild(MatChipList) chipList: MatChipList;
```

Getting the chipList with ViewChild annotation and then iterating over the chips and setting their color but this doesn't work. After selecting a second chip, the first chip gets a white color again.

```
onSectorChipSelect(sector: string) {
    if (this.filteredSectors.includes(sector)) {
      this.filteredSectors.splice(this.filteredSectors.indexOf(sector), 1);
    } else {
      this.filteredSectors.push(sector);
    }

    this.chipList.chips.forEach(chip => {
      if(this.filteredSectors.includes(chip.value)) {
        chip.selected = true;
        chip.color = 'primary';
      } else {
        chip.selected = false;
        chip.color = null;
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Does the browser re-render your component (and call chipColor) even if there is no actions from the user?

Comment: no, this doesn't happen. Only as soon as I move my mouse for example.

Comment: That's weird, by default Angular doesn't watch for mousemove events. It means mousemove doesn't trigger Angular change detector. Do you listen for mousemove event somewhere else in your app ?

Comment: no I don't .. it might just be how angular material components work? or specifically the chips? I could put together a stackblitz a bit later

Comment: Even if it does not answer your question at all. I think that at first, you should focus on limiting the number of changes detection on your whole application rather than optimizing a small loop. Once the change detection is OK, your optimization problem won't be so important anymore ;)